# Howto re-create the WSO2 ESB BasicAuth-handler sample using WSO2 Developer Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I need to create something like the BasicAuthHandler proposed on the [WSO2 ESB documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-BasicAutho) but using the WSO2 Developer Studio. On the WSO2 ESB documentation they suggest downloading one [existing example](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk07/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/samples/integration-scenarios/starbucks_sample/BasicAuth-handler/) but don't gives any clue about howto make it using WSO2 Developer Studio. Is not the WSO2 Developer Studio the right way of developing custom code for the WSO2 Carbon platform?

Comment: I download all the source code and try to import it into WSO2 Developer Studio as a maven project and it shows me the error: "Missing artifact org.apache.synapse:synapse-core:jar:2.1.1-wso2v2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Download the code
2. Run **mvn clean install -e**
3. Import the code as a maven project using the WSO2 Developer Studio 3.8.0

It work fine for me.

Please check that you have org.apache.synapse:synapse-core:jar:2.1.1-wso2v2 in your maven repo. you can add a wso2 maven repo to your pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Can you tell me from where i can download the dependencies? Is not documented on the product documentation page referenced above or on the code repository.

Comment: in pom.xml file you can find the dependency.

Comment: I can see in the pom file the name and version of the dependency i'm missing but i can't find in the pom file a location from where i can download the dependency.

Comment: I update my answer , please add the repository and run the command again.

Comment: Well it appears that updating the pom as you suggested is making it work. I think this need to be added to the POM on the repo don't you think?

Comment: I create an [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4440) so future documentation readers don't get stuck with the same problem.

Comment: great, please mark the answer as the right one. :-D